# Embed Kajabi into WP

Tags: javascript, embed

I am trying to embed kajabi into a WP page, I am using WPBakery if this is necesarry. The Kajabi is an email capture form and I need it to in a specific part of a page. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!
This is the sample code of kajabi

`<script src=https://mykajabiwebsite.com/forms/123456/embed.js></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE. When asking a question it is [recommended](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to include your research and what you've already tried in your question.

One option would be to turn the script into a shortcode with [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/). With a custom shortcode you can have any Kajabi form anywhere on your site as long as the shortcode takes the form ID as parameter. For example,

```
// add for example to child theme functions.php
add_shortcode( 'my_kajabi_form', 'kajabi_form_shortcode' );

function kajabi_form_shortcode( $atts ) {
  // assuming form ids are always integers
  if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) || ! is_numeric( $atts['id'] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  return sprintf(
    '<div class="kajabi-wrap">
      <script src="https://mykajabiwebsite.com/forms/%d/embed.js"></script>
    </div>',
    absint($atts['id'])
  );

}
```

Then use it in your post content with `[my_kajabi_form id="123456"]`.